# How to fix a compass that is turning in opposite direction?

Tags: compass, calibration

I am having an issue with my GS4 's compass. It turns in the opposite direction, i.e., if I turn right, it turns right with me when actually it should turn left w.r.t the screen. I tried calibrating it but the problem persists. Does anyone have any clue about what might be wrong ?

Comment: May be you are carrying something magnetic

Comment: No nothing magnetic  is near the phone. I don't use any case either.